# how to handle laravel socialite "Missing authorization Exception"

Tags: laravel, facebook-login, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

In Laravel Socialite We are redirected to facebook. But When User Cancels (not allowing facebook to access public profile) it is giving error Missing Authorization exception

> ClientException in RequestException.php line 107: Client error: GET
>   https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=1309844325833234&client_secret=1304bbdd28400tret49a295d324d577c&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback`
>    resulted in a 400 Bad Request response: {"error":{"message":"Missing
>    authorization
>    code","type":"OAuthException","code":1,"fbtrace_id":"Aq9wMwG6ewl"}}

I dont want to display this Instead I Want to return to my site home page by giving a message "Facebook Login Failed" like what shown in stackoverflow facebook login.

Answer (score 7):

Finally i got answer.Here it is

```
public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    try {
        $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        //Here you can write excepion Handling Logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try catch didn't give good result to me. I used below methods to catch this error. If you're using Laravel Socialite library definitely it has function call `handleProviderCallback`. In that use this code

**`handleProviderCallback` Method**

```
/**
 * Obtain the user information from GitHub.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function handleProviderCallback()
{

    $error_code = Input::get('error_code');

    if ($error_code == 200)
    {
        return redirect()->route('sign-in')->with('error','You\'ve chose not to grant us permission to connect with your Facebook account.');
    }
    else
    {
        $fbUser = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
        # rest of your code
    }
}
```

---

### Where does this `error_code` come from ??

Well, If you look at the error page(Laravel Black screened) come to you check the URL of that page. It has the these get methods `error` , `error_code` , `error_description` ,  `error_reason` ,  `state`.

> Ex : `http://localhost:8000/login/facebook/callback?error=access_denied&error_code=200&error_description=Permissions+error&error_reason=user_denied&state=mIxNjoDCogT2piMV5LX1Imk6GWNzqPUt3JZaqsIo#_=_`

---

### What I can do this to optimize this

You can use a `switch` statement based on error [Check this Facebook error codes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/error-reference/), with an error message and pass it.